# Add PostgreSQL row number to one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with the following columns: names, summary, etc...

I'm trying to add a row number at the end of each row in column 'names'.

for example, I have the name Christian in the first row of the column 'names' and I want it to also get the row number like this : Christian-1

I'm inserting to the table with the following command :

```
INSERT INTO people(name, summary)
VALUES ('Christian', 'some summary')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_names DO NOTHING;
```

What should I add to this insert command to also include each row's number?

Thanks in advance for any help you could give.

Comment: Do you want to update your current data or do you need an example how you should insert new data with the generated number appended?

Comment: Are you sure you really need this? What about only appending the ```id``` to the ```name``` during selection? If you persist the ```id``` (or what should be the "row number"?) also in the column ```name```, you are polluting the column

Comment: I want to insert new data with this feature. @Julius Tuskenis

Comment: yes the id will do too. actually, id is a better choice if possible. @Islingre

Comment: The very question itself and the example used *implies* a misconception.  **There is no such thing as a row number**. Data are stored unordered as sets of attributes (rows).  You can create a column whose value indicates relative ordering but it is not inherent to the database. It is user defined and user processed the RDBMS knows nothing of its purpose.

Comment: So I guess you have a sequence for your ```id``` (or use some ```SERIAL``` type). Just create yourself a view that has as part of the ```SELECT```-clause the following: ```name || '-' || id::text```. Do not put it directly into the ```name``` column of the table, this would be bad design! Only append the ```id``` on selection and use a ```VIEW``` so you do not have to write it everywhere. You can then just select from your view

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sequence for numbering the names - let's call it 'seq_num'.

Then when inserting you may use it.

```
INSERT INTO people(name, summary)
VALUES ('Christian'||nextval('seq_num')::text, 'some summary');
```

Comment: does it always append the (previous_row + 1) number? @Julius Tuskenis

Comment: It increments the sequence 1,2,3... Somehow counting records may lead to errors when there are 2 concurrent transactions - they both would evaluate the same number. Using a sequence is a proffered option for autoincrement value.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put this data directly into your table. This would pollute the data and there are other ways you can get your name with appended id.

Instead, make a view like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_people AS
SELECT *, name || '-' || id::text AS name_with_id
FROM people;
```

Wherever you need the `name` with the appended `id`, you can now query this view instead of the table and can just use the column `name_with_id`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to avoid duplicate names by appending a number specific to each name.  `ON CONFLICT` doesn't help, because it *updates* a row when there is a conflict.

You can do this by fixing the query that does the insert.  Here is logic that works if names are never deleted or updated:

```
insert into t (name)
    select v.name ||
           coalesce(nullif(('-' || cnt + row_number() over (partition by v.name order by v.name) - 1), '-0'), '')
    from (values ('X'), ('X'), ('Y')) v(name) cross join lateral
         (select count(*) as cnt
          from t
          where split_part(t.name, '-', 1) = v.name
         ) n;
```

The immutability of names may not be a safe assumption.  You can add one to the existing number by using similar logic:

```
insert into t (name)
    select v.name ||
           coalesce(nullif(('-' || cnt + row_number() over (partition by v.name order by v.name) - 1), '-0'), '')
    from (values ('X'), ('X'), ('Y')) v(name) cross join lateral
         (select max(cast(nullif(split_part(t.name, '-', 2), '') as int )) + 1 as cnt
          from t
          where split_part(t.name, '-', 1) = v.name
         ) n;
```

Note that both these solutions assume that the base `name` does not have a hyphen.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=32ad217d5f5692977f13cf64d31974a5) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: No actually what I'm trying to do is to generate a name that should have a specific id at the end of it. My example was not appropriate for this. I just want something like ""number += 1"" (in python) at the end of each name. @Gordon Linoff